# Pulling Data out of one spread sheet to fill data boxes on another spread sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am mainly looking for guidance on how to start a project.

Sprdsht 1 is set up as a table with the rows containing specific data for that location and the columns containing the parameters (i.e. A:K= name, emission data, model #, etc).  Sprdsht 2 is structured as a form with multiple boxes.  I am trying to import data from sprdsht 1 to sprdsht 2 and am wondering if it is possible to import only one row of data at a time to complete the form (i.e F1:F11) using a macro or VBA.

If so, how would the code look?

Also, is using excel the best way to handle this function or would another program (i.e. Access) work better?

Comment: yes it's possible, but what have you tried so far? For example, you could use a Data query and ADO Recordset to read the data one record at a time...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one of the many ways to get started:

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("FirstWorkbook.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("OtherWorkbook.xlsx")
    Set sheet1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
    Set rng1 = sheet1.Range("A2:K2", Range("A2:K2").End(xlDown))
    Set rng2 = sheet2.Range("F1:F11")
    For i = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To 11
            rng2(j, 1).Value = rng1(i, j).Value
        Next
        Call FunctionThatSubmitsTheFormInSheet2
    Next
End Sub
```